# Terraform join interpolation not appending to last element

Tags: terraform, hcl

I have a snippet that creates a list of Vmware machines like so..

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "os-lb" {
count                       = 3
```

And then later in my file, I create a variable list to pass to a template like so...

`vm.tf` excerpt...

```
list_masters = join(format(".comapny.com %v", "openshift_node_labels=\"{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'west'}\"\n"), vsphere_virtual_machine.os-lb.*.name)}
```

`inventory.tpl` excerpt..

```
# host group for etcd
[etcd]
${list_master}
```

But the rendered template doesn't append the desired `.company.com` string to the last element. See the below snippet from the rendered template.

```
openshift-node-0.company.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'west'}"
openshift-node-1.company.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'west'}"
openshift-node-2
```

I'm not sure what I should be doing differently so the string is also appended to the last element of the list. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to worked for me. If below did not work please provide me snippets which are enough for me to recreate on my machine.

```
static_routes = "${join("\n", formatlist("up route add -net %s.%s.0/24 gw %s dev %s", var.cluster_nets_prefix, openstack_compute_instance_v2.kube-worker.*.metadata.worker_number,openstack_compute_instance_v2.kube-worker.*.access_ip_v4, var.if_dev))}"
```

Regards
Sudhakar